# Play DRM token encrypted video on custom player

Tags: azure, video-streaming, azure-media-services, drm

I have a backend service that calls Azure Media Services, uploading a video with DRM and creating a token for it.

When testing the result in https://ampdemo.azureedge.net/ It works great.
I want to show this video on my own video player as well (VideoJS) but I can't figure out how to set the token there, I use it with react and could not find anything remote to help on this subject.

Any suggestions or answers?

Answer (score 0):

We do have some sample projects on Git Hub that demonstrates the various third party player and how to support DRM with them.

Some 3rd party players can support DRM, while others do not.

Check this repository where we keep track of the 3rd party player support.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-3rdparty-player-samples

There are some test cases for Video.jS with DRM up here that should answer your question.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-3rdparty-player-samples/tree/master/src/video.js

Comment: I actually tried this repo with the video js and added the token but the video just kept loading with no result.

Comment: Check your results against the test matrix for Video JS here 
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-3rdparty-player-samples/tree/master/docs/video.js#test-results

Comment: Tried the following link: https://amssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/3b970ae0-39d5-44bd-b3a3-3136143d6435/AzureMediaServicesPromo.ism/manifest

which is the on demand sample in amp without DRM just to check and it still loading and stuck on 
22:44:46.743 [DEBUG] VHS: PlaybackWatcher > initialize.
console shows error : Uncaught Error: DASH_INVALID_XML

Comment: Likely because that is the Smooth manifest you passed in. /manifest will give you Smooth Streaming Format. 
/manifest(format=mpd-time-cmaf) will give you DASH with CMAF format
/manfiest(format=m3u8-cmaf) will give you HLS manifest with CMAF format

Comment: VideoJS does not support Smooth Streaming XML format manifest - and expects DASH or HLS (if configured with that extension)